# text align center not working

Tags: css

I'm having a big issue in aligning the text in center of the following html and css:

html:

```
<article class="item-page">
  <p>
     text-align not working...
  </p>
</article>
```

css:

```
article {
    display: table-row;
    color: #f00;
}
p{
    text-align: center;
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ufa0zat6/)

Comment: I've posted this Q/A hoping that further future user will not involve in research for hours of time like I faced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The key problem was because of using `display: table-row;`.

Use `display:table;width:100%` to it's parent, then only p also behaves as it is 100% wide then it can have center align of the width:

html:

```
<main>
<article class="item-page">
      <p>
         text-align not working...
      </p>
</article>
</main>
```

css:

```
main{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
article {
    display: table-row;
    color: #f00;
}
p{
    text-align: center;
}
```

## [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ufa0zat6/1/)

---

Why is this so?

Because when the content is inside table-layout the width works dynamically as per the content width (i.e. width is auto) and setting table to 100% makes it sure to be 100% wide.

Comment: Just giving the `<p>` a static width (e.g. `width:500px`) will work too.  The `text-align:center` is working; it's just that the `<p>` is only as wide as the text, so there is no blank space in which to center it.

Comment: But that's not good way, by the way, I've tried that technique before I knew that it should be displayed as table and have width 100%...